# Best way to return data In JSON

Tags: jquery, html, json, woocommerce

Hi everyone I use ajax to modified a div in my website

I have this function that work perfect, but I have a problem to gets the value that return

```
updatecart = function(qty, id_product) {
    var currentVal, data, id, item_hash, request;
    currentVal = void 0;
    id = void 0;
    data = void 0;
    item_hash = void 0;
    currentVal = parseFloat(qty);
    id = parseInt(id_product);
    request = $.ajax({
      url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        quantity: currentVal,
        id_product: id,
        action: 'update_my_cart',
        dataType: "json"
      },
      success: function(html, data) {
        var array_fields, fields, pos, total_amount;
        pos = html.indexOf("[");
        fields = html.slice(pos + 1, -1);
        array_fields = fields.split(',');
        id = parseInt(array_fields[0].replace(/\"/g, ""));
        total_amount = (array_fields[1] + ',' + array_fields[2]).replace(/[\\"]/g, '');
        $('.total' + id + ' .woocommerce-Price-amount').replaceWith($(total_amount));
        $('.amount_cart .amount').replaceWith('.amount', html);
        console.log('update cart');
      },
      error: function(errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });   };
```

in this case return html and data.

data = "success"

and html is

```
<div class="total_purchase">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="subtotal_cart">
      <span class="item_purchase">
        Sub-total:      </span>
      <span class="amount_cart">
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">15,40&nbsp;<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">&euro;</span></span>      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="wc-proceed-to-checkout">

<a href="http:../checkout/" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">
    Checkout</a>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

I have to cut and work with the string to get my date, and replace the div at the end.

And even in the last line I have problem to replace the data

```
$('.amount_cart .amount').replaceWith('.amount', html);
```

What is a best way or return the date in other way to get the info that I need.

Thanks in advice!

Comment: You aren't displaying your `update_my_cart()` ajax callback. Though John's answer is what you will need to add to that callback.

Answer (score 0):

Server side you have to return the date with json_encode()

```
json_encode(array( 'mydate' => $my_date ));
```

And if you want to display the date inside your HTML, you have to do this in your ajax success.

```
success: function(json) {
    $('.amount_cart .amount').html(json.mydate);
}
```